# Read fp_arith_inst_retired.scalar_single

Tags: c++, performance

I've got a quite complex C++ program and would like to read the fp_arith_inst_retired.scalar_single PMU of my processor before/after a code block so I can calculate different flop values for this region.

Is there beside using perf a suitable way doing this? Perf measures the complete executable and that's quite a lot ...

Comment: `perf` can also annotate the assembly or source per instruction/line with the counter. What in particular is the problem with it?

Comment: Okay. Then I missed this opportunity. I'll give it a try. Perfing the whole application will produce too much "noise" ... I'm only interested in the performance of a single part of my code

Comment: Try `man perf-record` and `man perf-annotate`.